# Why do I get "Invalid use of :: (scope resolution operator)?"

Tags: c++, build, cmake, std, gnu-make

I'm building a data structures project using `cmake` and I built an array class.

I used `std::size_t` as a parameter for my default constructor. 
But when I try to build the project an error appears saying `Invalid use of ::`

I tried `using namespace std;` but also didn't work.

barra.h file

```
#ifndef BARRAY_H
#define BARRAY_H

class BArray
{
public:
    BArray() = delete;                            //Declare the default constructor as deleted to avoid
                                                  //declaring an array without specifying its size.
    BArray(std::size_t);
    BArray(int, int);                             //Constructor that initializes the array with init_val.
private:
    int* array;
    int length;
};

#endif // BARRAY_H
```

And barray.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "barray.h"

BArray::BArray(std::size_t init_size)
{
    array = new int[init_size]();
    length = init_size;
}

BArray::BArray(int init_size, int init_val)
{
    array = new int[init_size];
    length = init_size;

    for(int i = 0; i < init_size; ++i)
        array[i] = init_val;
}
```

Error message:

error: invalid use of `::`

Comment: Have you included anything, or is your header file exactly as is?

Comment: @Tas No, the header file is exactly as is.

Comment: @BilalAhmed [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22c3d731444c1bbe). Post a [mcve] reproducing the problem as required please.

Comment: Your header file needs to include where `std::size_t` is defined if you are to use it.

Comment: See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for the include you can use.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks so much.

Comment: Why is one statement `array = new int[int_size]();` and the other `array = new int[int_size];` (without the parens)?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In the first statement, the parentheses are used to initialize the array to zeros. 
While in the second one, there is already a parameter called init_val that is used to initialize the array with the user passed argument.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following header file and it should work.

`#include <cstddef>`